# Modify SVG components defined within a <defs><g> and used in a <use>

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using SVG and I have a component that I want to reuse. e.g:

```
<defs>
<g id="3WayValve">
  <line x1="33" y1="20" x2="33" y2="25" stroke = "black"></line>
  <line x1="33" y1="42" x2="33" y2="47" stroke = "black"></line>
  <line x1="43" y1="33" x2="48" y2="33" stroke = "black"></line>
  <polygon id="In" points="25,23 33,33 40,23" stroke="black" fill="green"></polygon>
  <polygon id="Out" points="25,42 33,33 40,42" stroke="black" fill="white"></polygon>
  <polygon id="Bypass" points="43,25 33,33 43,41" stroke="black" fill="green"></polygon>
  <polygon id="Alert" points="20,20 48,20 48,45 20,45" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></polygon>
</g>
```

```
  <use id="I1" x = "50" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValve" visibility="visible"/>
```

What I would like to be able to do is modify the fill attribute on ID="IN" using javascript.

I can modify attributes within the use tag e.g.

```
document.querySelector(".InletsComponent").getSVGDocument().querySelector(".InletsComponentImage").getElementById("I1").setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
```

but how do I access the inner components in the same way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to change the fill attribute of all the elements in the `g` object through styling of the `use` elements, then you should **not** declare a fill in the `g` elements.

```
<defs>
    <g id="3WayValve">
        <polygon id="In" points="25,23 33,33 40,23" stroke="black"></polygon>
    ...
```

Now if you apply a fill to the `use` objects, they will be inherited by the objects that do not have a `fill` defined (but ignored bu the ones that do).

If you have

```
<use id="I1" x="50" y="50"   xlink:href = "#3WayValve" visibility="visible"/>
<use id="I2" x="100" y="100" xlink:href = "#3WayValve" visibility="visible"/>
```

You can change the color of each one separately:

```
document.getElementById("I1").setAttribute("fill", "red");
document.getElementById("I2").setAttribute("fill", "green");
```

See this updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Sw877/6/)**.

Comment: What happens if I have 2 use tags with ID="I1" and ID="I2" how do I change just the I1 fill attribute?

Comment: The fill attribute of the `use` element is not the same as the `fill` attribute of the `polygon`. Some polygons are white. If you want you can locate the `use` element by ID (and not use the ID of the individual polygon). You can locate its `href` element to discover the ID of the `g` element it refers to, and then, from there, locate the polygon you want to change.

Comment: For example, this gets you the referred ID: `var g1id = document.getElementById("I1").getAttribute("xlink:href").substring(1)`. You can use it to get the `g` object:  `var g1 = document.getElementById(g1id)`. Then you can get the contents of `g` and change its attributes: `g1.getElementsByTagName("polygon")[0].setAttribute("fill", "red")`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it's not quite what I wanted. I want to be able to have multiple instances of the component on the screen e.g multiple Use tags. but I want to be able to change the fill attribute on individual components e.g. referring to my original code. ID1.IN.FILL = Green and ID2.IN.Fill = Red.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Ok. I understood what you want. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help, but it's still not quite what I want.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help, but it's still not quite what I want. Using the code in your example, if I add another line <use id="I2" x="100" y="100" xlink:href = "#3WayValve" visibility="visible"/> when I execute the code there are now 2 images, but they both look the same i.e. have red fills. It appears that the example is changing the actual base (Def) component attributes. What I need to do is have 2 images using the base image def, but I want to be able to individually change the appearance of each image and not the base image (in def), basically treat them as separate components.

Comment: Did you see the updated JSFiddle I posted in the edited answer? It has two objects (use) and each of them with a different color.

Comment: The one in the answer, not the one in the comments. This one: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Sw877/6/

Comment: All you have to do is *remove* the `fill` attributes from your defined images, since you can't *override* them in the `use` object, but you can *define* them.

Comment: Hi thanks again, sorry I'm being really slow! The example you updated does update individual components. Using setAttribute("fill", "red") changes the colour of the polygons that don't have a fill attribute. If the fill attribute is present then it does not overwrite it. If I add a fill="none" to all of the polygons the example doesn't work. What I am aiming for is to be able to change just 1 of the polygon fill colours on 1 of the components. e.g. I want to change the fill attribute on the polygon with ID="IN" on Component with ID="I1" only and I don't want anything else will change.

Comment: I have changed my approach to this problem, but unfortunately have ended up with the same problem. I am now using CSS see example http://jsfiddle.net/Sw877/90/  The first example shows the independant setting of components. The second shows the independent setting of shapes within the component. What I need to do is achieve example 2 with each square in a different color but I want to be able to control N1 and N2 separately. If I use the javascript to change the class attribute on N2 it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution that works, but I am not very happy with it. The solution:

```
<svg>
<defs>
    <symbol id="3WayValveIn">
      <line x1="33" y1="20" x2="33" y2="25" stroke = "black"></line>
      <line x1="33" y1="42" x2="33" y2="47" stroke = "black"></line>
      <line x1="43" y1="33" x2="48" y2="33" stroke = "black"></line>
      <polygon id="In" points="25,23 33,33 40,23" stroke="black"></polygon>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="3WayValveOut">
      <polygon id="Out" points="25,42 33,33 40,42" stroke="black"></polygon>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="3WayValveBypass">
      <polygon id="Bypass" points="43,25 33,33 43,41" stroke="black"></polygon>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="3WayValveAlert">
      <polygon id="Alert" points="20,20 48,20 48,45 20,45" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></polygon>
    </symbol>        
</defs>

<use  id="I1IN" x = "50" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveIn" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I1OUT" x = "50" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveOut" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I1BYPASS" x = "50" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveBypass" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I1ALERT" x = "50" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveAlert" visibility="visible"/>

<use  id="I2IN" x = "100" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveIn" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I2OUT" x = "100" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveOut" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I2BYPASS" x = "100" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveBypass" visibility="visible"/>
<use  id="I2ALERT" x = "100" y = "50" xlink:href = "#3WayValveAlert" visibility="visible"/>
```

I have had to break 1 component up into 4 symbols and then add it to the page using 4 use tags to create the component.

I can then modify the individual bits using:

```
document.getElementById("I1IN").setAttribute("fill", "white");
document.getElementById("I1OUT").setAttribute("fill", "green");
document.getElementById("I1BYPASS").setAttribute("fill", "green");

document.getElementById("I2IN").setAttribute("fill", "green");
document.getElementById("I2OUT").setAttribute("fill", "white");
document.getElementById("I2BYPASS").setAttribute("fill", "green");
```

Does anyone know of a better way that this can be done to minimise the number of use tags for each component? but still be able to modify the indivdual bits.